# Using Art instead of Dalvik to compile

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, dalvik

I'm using Eclipse and I have a new project using android version 21 (5.0). I want to compile it using Art instead of Dalvik. What I have to do to achieve that?

Edit : The reason of the question is that I have this problem:

```
[2014-11-12 10:30:49 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2014-11-12 10:30:49 - MAMUT] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I expected than doing that I solve the problem:

> Of particular note is the suggestion of making a minSdkVersion 21 dev
>   build - this allows you to generate multi-dex output incrementally in
>   the new ART format, making for a much faster development iteration
>   cycle (at least on Android 5.0 devices).

Thanks

Comment: by doing "minSdkVersion = 21", your app only run on lollipop. I think this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of particular note is the suggestion of making a minSdkVersion 21 dev build - this allows you to generate multi-dex output incrementally in the new ART format, making for a much faster development iteration cycle (at least on Android 5.0 devices).

That's wrong and should read roughly

> Of particular note is the suggestion of using *Android Build Tools 21.1 and higher* together with the [Multidex Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex) - this allows you to use multiple dex files in the `dex` format which hasn't changed at all, making for unchanged development.

The problem of the `dex` format is that it can't contain more than 65536 methods. The solution is to simpliy split the output into multiple `dex` files. There are 2 problems we had in the past

- the `dx` tool was not capable to produce multiple dex files
- it's very complicated to use multiple dex files on a device since devices load only 1 dex file and the code in the other ones has to be loaded somehow manually.

Build tools 21 solve the first problem, you can simply generate multiple dex files by just adding the `-multi-dex` flag to the compile options.

The multidex support library solves the second problem. It tells those devices how to load additional dex files. And the ART runtime on Lollipop and above (4.4 had ART too but can't do the same) is capable of using multiple files without being told how to do so.

Also relevant is the official [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) document.

Comment: I don't know how to tell to Eclipse that sets the --multi-dex=true. I'm not using gradle and trying to set dex.multi.dex=true on project.properties doesn't work

Comment: @Plebios it's unfortunately impossible to build apks with eclipse once you hit the method limit. The Android Eclipse plugin does not support that as of now. Maybe in the future but I kind of doubt it because they focus on gradle and android studio. If you wish to continue using Eclipse: create a gradle build script and instead of letting eclipse build apks for you do it from a command line or via a gradle plugin. The alternative is to import the project into Android Studio which makes the project pretty unusable for Eclipse but creates gradle automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
I want to compile it using Art instead of Dalvik.
```

Art and Dalvik are not compiler, they are virtual machine. They executed the bytecode generated by the compiler (your application)

Comment: I want to generate Art bytecode instead of Dalvik bytecode

Comment: you   have to do nothing

Comment: @Plebios The bytecode is exactly the same, Art vs Dalvik are just different approaches how a device can interpret the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need an emulator or real device which is running ART.

Check this: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html